# Input text and radio calculation by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help for calculate values by text and radio input field. Here is HTML code:

```html
<input type="text" id="num" name="num" />

<input type="radio" name="yesno" value="yes"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="yesno" value="no"> No

<input type="text" id="result" name="result" />
```

Now I want to calculate value of by some of conditions:

1. IF radio button value no then `input#result` will show same value as `input#num`
2. IF radio button value yes then result will show value based on conditional cal culation:

   a. IF `input#num = 1-10` then `input#result = input#num * 4`

   b. IF `input#num = 11-20` then `input#result = input#num * 3.5`

   c. IF `input#num = 21-50` then `input#result = input#num * 3`

   d. IF `input#num = 51-100` then `input#result = input#num * 2.5`

   e. IF `input#num = 101-200` then `input#result = input#num * 2`

   f. IF `input#num = 200+` then `input#result = input#num * 1.5`

Please help me. I don't know javascript very much so I need your help. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I don't know javascript too much but I know PHP. That's I don't understand how to start. And I haven't tried yet.

Comment: apni ki bangladeshi ?? @HarunRRayhan

Comment: Yap bro I'm Bangladeshi @AnikIslamAbhi

Comment: @HarunRRayhan glad to see a bangladeshi :)

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi apnar fb id deya jabe?

Comment: off course . https://goo.gl/PRaXuc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
        var value = $("#num").val();
        var result = 0;
        if (value <= 10) {
            result = value * 4;
        } else if (value <= 20) {
            result = value * 3.5;
        }
        $("#result").val(result);
    } else {
        $("#result").val($("#num").val());
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=yesno]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'no') {
        $("#result").val($("#num").val())
    } else {
        var ten = $("#num").val();

        if (ten <= 10) {
            var total = parseFloat(ten) * 4;
            $("#result").val(total);
        } else if (ten <= 20 && ten >= 11) {
            var total = parseFloat(ten) * 3.5;
            $("#result").val(total);
        }
    }
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dn1grrx3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the matter of not knowing how to access html elements via JS.

- You can check which radio button is selected using `$("[name=yesno]:checked").val();` return Yes/No
- You can set value of html element using `$("#result").val(someval)`